# How to show the scheme (including type) of a parquet file from command line or spark shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I have determined how to use the spark-shell to show the field names but it's ugly and does not include the type

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

println(sqlContext.parquetFile(path))
```

prints:

```
ParquetTableScan [cust_id#114,blar_field#115,blar_field2#116], (ParquetRelation /blar/blar), None
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
sqlContext.read.parquet(path).printSchema()
```

From [Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html):

```
// Print the schema in a tree format
df.printSchema()
// root
// |-- age: long (nullable = true)
// |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I have an OK way of doing it, just peek the first row to infer the scheme.  (Though not sure just how elegant this is, what if it happens to be empty?? I'm sure there has to be a better solution)

```
sqlContext.parquetFile(p).first()
```

At some point prints:

```
{
  optional binary cust_id;
  optional binary blar;
  optional double foo;
}
 fileSchema: message schema {
  optional binary cust_id;
  optional binary blar;
  optional double foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of parquetFile() is a SchemaRDD (1.2) or DataFrame (1.3) which have the .printSchema() method.

Comment: Please can you show what the output looks like? Does it include the type information? I haven't been able to test this yet as I'm still on 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In Spark SQL:

```
describe query select * from parquet.`/path/to/file`;
```